# Move Redrex Stepper Motor using Accel

Tags: arduino

I am connecting a stepper motor to arduino Mega. I am trying to set the stepper motor position to 100 when pressing to c and when it's in the position 100 I want to return to the default position which is 0. However it is not working. Stepper motor is moving few steps slowly and do not get to the normal position.

```
while (input_m=='c') {
   stepperM.stop();
   stepperT.moveTo(100);
   stepperT.setSpeed(200);
   stepperT.runSpeedToPosition();

   if (stepperT.targetPosition()==100) {
      stepperT.moveTo(0);
      stepperT.setSpeed(200);
      stepperT.runSpeedToPosition();
      input_m= '0';
  }
 Serial.print("Finish \n");
 Serial.println("");
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Mate first of all I am sure you have checked your wirings. Check if your power supply is able to drive the motor, as far as I understand from your description, you need at least 1.5 Amps. Then try to reduce the speed.
Posting the full code will help finding the programming issue if there is one. Thanks.